# Do script from another file

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

im today stared learning some ajax technology and im done that when im pressing the button im getting text from another file with functions but they dont working.

My main file

```
<html>
<head>
    <script>
        function showHint(str) {
                var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
                xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
                    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                        document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
                    }
                };
                xmlhttp.open("GET", "request/testa.php?q=" + str, true);
                xmlhttp.send();
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<button id="inp" style="background-color: #0000FF; color: #ffffff" onclick="showHint(this.value)">
    Just do it!
</button>
<p><span id="txtHint"></span></p>
</html>
```

and in file which send me text (request/testa.php) is

```
test 2

    <script>

        document.getElementById("inp").value="You did it!";
        document.getElementById("inp").style.backgroundColor="ffffff";
    </script>
```

and tekst working fine, i got text "test 2" and script but that not works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Writing javascript code into your page using innerHTML will not execute the script.

The easiest way around this is to use jQuery's [load](http://api.jquery.com/load/), which *will* execute the scripts for you.

Comment: There's no jQuery here.

Comment: What can i do when i dont have jquery or i dont want to use it?

Comment: Move the code you want to execute into your `onreadystatechange` function. Otherwise, you'll need to add in some hacks to pull out the script page from the loaded file and execute.

Answer (score 0):

You have to change something in testa.php. Put everything in a function or just remove the script tag.

```
    function MyScript(){
        document.getElementById("inp").value="You did it!";
        document.getElementById("inp").style.backgroundColor="ffffff";
    }
```

or

```
    document.getElementById("inp").value="You did it!";
    document.getElementById("inp").style.backgroundColor="ffffff";
```

After that you can replace the `innerHTML` in your showHint function for the `eval` function.

```
   document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
```

for

```
    eval(xmlhttp.responseText);
```

but have in mind that the eval function opens the door for bugs or hacks.